# Feeds del Chat de SOes

Tags: discusión, chat, rss

En [el chat oficial](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), existe la opción de agregar feeds RSS. Esto permite que se agregue contenido (publicaciones en el sitio, blogs, etc.) que pueden aparecer como mensajes.

¿Les parece que deberíamos agregar algo de esto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alto!  No quiero que aparezca nada de esto en el chat.

Me interesa mucho leer feeds , pero no quisiera que el chat se vea como un canal de noticas en slack .. al chat de SOES lo veo un canal off-topic!

Propongo que tengamos otra sala exclusiva para esto y que pongamos todos los feeds que nos parezcan necesarios. Y este podria convertirse en un nucleo de informacion interesante. Pero el chat dejemoslo como esta

Comment: No estaba pensando en nada ni remotamente parecido a Slack. Las sugerencias implicaban como máximo 1 mensaje por semana, o incluso menos. Sin embargo, debería haber empezado por acá. Así que modifiqué la pregunta para dar lugar a esta discusión.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sería bueno agregar algo más de contenido, pero siendo muy cuidadosos en qué se está incorporando. Sobre todo, asegurándonos de que tengan muy baja frecuencia de publicación.

Pensaría en agregar publicaciones que todos leemos, o que normalmente terminan enlazadas en el chat por algún usuario, y que sería práctico dejar que se publiquen automáticamente. Me refiero a feeds que estén en el rango de 1 publicación por semana, 1 por mes, o similar.

Por ejemplo, podríamos agregar [el blog de Stack Overflow en español](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/juanm/).

Comment: Me agrada la idea de agregar el feed del Blog de SOes. El del xkcd en primera instancia parecía buena idea pero si no está activo, preferiría que no se agregara, si acaso a una sala dedicada a feeds.